# Show div based on dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show divs based on two dropdown selections. For example, if user selects width = 7.00M and Length = 20.0M, I want to show all divs which has width value  7.0 and length <= 20. Any help would be highly appreciated.
I have been trying this for a long but not able to achieve the desired output.

```css
div {
background-color: #f4f4f4;
width:130px;
float:left;
margin: 20px 20px;
}
#form-field-width {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>

</style>

<h1>Please select the package</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="dimensions">Choose Dimensions:</label>
 <select name="form_fields[width]" id="form-field-width" class="" required="required" aria-required="true">
 <option value="6.20M">6.20M</option>
 <option value="6.57M">6.57M</option>
 <option value="7.10M">7.10M</option>
 <option value="9.42M">9.42M</option>
  <option value="10.00M">10.00M</option>
 </select>
  <select name="form_fields[Length]" id="form-field-Length" class="" required="required" aria-required="true">
  <option value="25.70M">25.70M</option>
  <option value="24.22M">24.22M</option>
  <option value="21.00M">21.00M</option>
  <option value="13.73M">13.73M</option>
  <option value="21.15M">21.15M</option>
  </select>
    <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Based on your selection of width and length, here are the packages.</p>

<div class="package1">
<p>Package 1</p>
<p>Width - 6.20M</p>
<p>Length - 25.70M</p>
</div>

<div class="package2">
<p>Package 2</p>
<p>Width - 6.57M</p>
<p>Length - 24.22M</p>
</div>

<div class="package3">
<p>Package 3</p>
<p>Width - 7.10M</p>
<p>Length - 21.00M</p>
</div>

<div class="package4">
<p>Package 4</p>
<p>Width - 9.42M</p>
<p>Length - 13.73M</p>
</div>

<div class="package5">
<p>Package 5</p>
<p>Width - 10.00M</p>
<p>Length - 21.15M</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your js script ? did you tried to add an event on the submit button and check if selected value == xxM $('packageX').show() and hide the others using .hide()

Comment: "I have been trying this for a long but not able to achieve the desired output." - Please include your previous attempts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following logic to filter the parent divs and show / hide it

```js
$(function() {
  $('#form-field-width, #form-field-Length').on('change', function() {
    var width = $('#form-field-width').val();
    var length = $('#form-field-Length').val();
    //console.log(width + "  " + length);
    $('.myle').hide();
    $('.myle').filter(function() {
      var first = $(this).find('p:first').text();
      var last = $(this).find('p:last').text();
      //console.log(first + "  " + last);
      if (first.indexOf(width)>=0) {
        var value = parseFloat(last.replace('Length - ','')) || 0;
       // console.log(value);
        if (parseFloat(length) >= value) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 20px;
}

#form-field-width {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Please select the package</h1>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="dimensions">Choose Dimensions:</label>
  <select name="form_fields[width]" id="form-field-width" class="" required="required" aria-required="true">
    <option value="6.20M">6.20M</option>
    <option value="6.57M">6.57M</option>
    <option value="7.10M">7.10M</option>
    <option value="9.42M">9.42M</option>
    <option value="10.00M">10.00M</option>
  </select>
  <select name="form_fields[Length]" id="form-field-Length" class="" required="required" aria-required="true">
    <option value="25.70M">25.70M</option>
    <option value="24.22M">24.22M</option>
    <option value="21.00M">21.00M</option>
    <option value="13.73M">13.73M</option>
    <option value="21.15M">21.15M</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Based on your selection of width and length, here are the packages.</p>

<div class="myle">Package 1
  <p>Width - 6.20M</p>
  <p>Length - 25.70M</p>
</div>

<div class="myle">Package 2
  <p>Width - 6.57M</p>
  <p>Length - 24.22M</p>
</div>

<div class="myle">Package 3
  <p>Width - 7.10M</p>
  <p>Length - 21.00M</p>
</div>

<div class="myle">Package 4
  <p>Width - 9.42M</p>
  <p>Length - 13.73M</p>
</div>

<div class="myle">Package 5
  <p>Width - 10.00M</p>
  <p>Length - 21.15M</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Bhushan. I have implemented your solution and it is working as expected. Cheers.

Comment: happy to help you :), you can upvote and accept this answer if find it useful

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example with one select and onchange event :

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <style>
    div {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    width:130px;
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    }
    #form-field-width {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
      .package{
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    
    <h1>Please select the package</h1>
    
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="dimensions">Choose Dimensions:</label>
     <select name="form_fields[width]" id="form-field-width" class="" required="required" aria-required="true">
       <option value="">-----</option>
     <option value="package1">6.20M</option>
     <option value="package2">6.57M</option>
     <option value="package3">7.10M</option>
     <option value="package4">9.42M</option>
      <option value="package5">10.00M</option>
     </select>
        <br><br>
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
    
    <p>Based on your selection of width and length, here are the packages.</p>
      
    <div class="package" id="package1">
    <p>Package 1</p>
    <p>Width - 6.20M</p>
    <p>Length - 25.70M</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="package" id="package2">
    <p>Package 2</p>
    <p>Width - 6.57M</p>
    <p>Length - 24.22M</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="package" id="package3">
    <p>Package 3</p>
    <p>Width - 7.10M</p>
    <p>Length- 21.00M</p>
</div>

<div class="package" id="package4">
<p>Package 4</p>
<p>Width - 9.42M</p>
<p>Length - 13.73M</p>
</div>

<div class="package" id="package5">
<p>Package 5</p>
<p>Width - 10.00M</p>
<p>Length - 21.15M</p>
</div>

</body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

> js :

```
$('#form-field-width').change(function(){ 
    var value = $(this).val();
  if(value){
$(".package").hide()
  $("#"+value).show()
  }else $(".package").hide()
  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Amine. Appreciated mate.